# slqalchemy operational error when executed on boot

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have an alarm script written in python that gathers alarms from a sqlite database.

If I execute the script: python /home/pi/VRobot/alarm.V2.py everything works fine.

When I place it in the execute it in /etc/profile and run it on boot I get the following error.

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: reminders [SQL: u'SELECT reminders.id AS reminders_id, reminders.activity AS reminders_activity, reminders.time AS reminders_time, reminders.day AS reminders_day, reminders.song AS reminders_song, reminders.timeofday AS reminders_timeofday \nFROM reminders'] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)`

The /etc/profile script looks like the following:

```sh
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi

amixer set 'PCM' 100%
python /home/pi/VRobot/alarm.V2.py &
```

Any ideas to why the script works fine when ran normally but when executed on boot it does not?

I do it like this:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db', echo=True)
```

So I use a relative path to connect to the database.

Comment: So what path are you using to connect to the database? Is it a relative or absolute path?

Comment: The error usually indicates that you are opening a different absolute path from the one that works, resolving to an empty database.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do it like this: engine = create_engine('sqlite:///foo.db', echo=True)
So I use a relative path to connect to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a relative path to connect to your database; this makes you dependent on the current working directory. That current working directory differs when you run from the `/etc/profile` script, at which point you connect to an empty database.

Either change the current working directory to that of the script (`cd` in shell code or `os.chdir()` in Python), or use an absolute path.

You could *generate* an absolute path from the `__file__` value:

```
import os.path

HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
database_path = os.path.join(HERE, 'foo.db')
database_uri = 'sqlite:///{}'.format(database_path)
```

Then use `create_engine(database_uri, echo=True)` to connect.

Comment: I chose to use the absolute path directly and it works like a charm!